# iPhone Enterprise Development

Tags: iphone, enterprise

I am currently looking into developing a project for an enterprise environment and I have a couple of questions:

Question 1: I was wondering what are the server requirements for this can it be done on any server or can this be done through IIS?

Question 2: Currently the criteria is 500 employees and a Dunn and Bradstreet number, does this mean 500 users with devices or that a company must have a minimum of 500 employees before the enterprise functionality can be used?

Question 3: If a company has less than 500 users is there any other option for in house application deployment?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Q1.

I assume you are referring to the communication between the iPhone and a server that offers functionality for that iPhone. This could be done with any server, as long as it exposes web services which can be picked up by the iPhone with HTTP POSTs and GETs and the provided XML parser.

Another good solution would be to look into the Google App Engine (or another cloud based system such as that) to act as your server component. I haven't used it yet, but I did hear a lot of good things about it from other iPhone developers.

I don't understand the other two questions though. Maybe you could expand on them.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The 500 user limit for the iPhone Developer Enterprise Program (IDEP) has been lifted in Fall 2011. The only thing you need now is a DUNS number (this is free if you apply - but you may have to wait 30 days).

See [my blog](http://blog.apperian.com/2010/10/apple-opens-ios-developer-enterprise.html) for full information on the program changes.